# Store html form answer as a variable to be used back on the form-page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm really new at using PHP, and I'm not really sure what kind of solution I need to be looking for, but anyway... 
I have created a mini-form, that only has one question. I have used a select-tag and seven option-tags. I want to save the answer from the user as a variable, that I can then use in an if-statement later, on the same page as the form was on. Is this even possible? And newbie-friendly?

Comment: all values from the form submitted to the server will be in either the `$_GET` or `$_POST` array. but i suggest finding some basic tutorials as this question is a poor fit for this site

Comment: well, I have tried looking at different tutorials, but none of them seems to work... I am also not sure if how to use the $_GET or $_POST array, like in a handler file or directly in the form-page?

Comment: I'm sure you can find a tutorial that works, S.O is for *specific* questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
1. Check that you have added method in `form` tag (action means that you will be using same page for your if-statement) and that you have name for `select` element:

```
<form action="?" method="get">
<select name="question"> 
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    ...
    <option value="7">seven</option>   
</select>
```

2. Then, after form submit the page will be reloaded and you will get selected value from `$_GET["question"]` variable.

Read more about it: [PHP $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using only PHP and HTML, it is not possible to pass a value back to the PHP script once the page has been sent to the user.

What you can do is to configure the form to be submitted to the same page. This way, you will be able to access the variable the next time your PHP script is executed.

For example, your form could look like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

After the user has pressed the submit button on this form, the values will be sent to the current page, where you can process them with PHP. They will be located inside the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays:

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) {

        processTheUserInput($_POST['userinput']);
    }

    // other PHP code
?>

// your HTML code
```